# Why isn't the compiler warning about incorrect formatters?

Tags: go, compiler-errors

I was expecting the [following code](https://go.dev/play/p/WdVXNNZEnOy) to at least raise a warning during compilation because the formatters are not aligned with the types of variables:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := "hello"
    fmt.Printf("1 %w", s)
    fmt.Printf("2 %s", s)
}
```

The types of the variables are known at compile time, and the string formatters are parsed in a deterministic way - is there a reason why the error is not raised at that point?

What I get instead is a code that outputs

```
1 %!w(string=hello)2 hello
```

This seems to be some kind of message telling that `%w` was wrong for the type `string` (but only at runtime)

Comment: Because it’s not a compilation error, it’s a runtime warning. Various linters doing static analysis will warn you ahead of time too

Comment: @JimB: is there a reason why this is not a compiler error? What is the rationale behind providing a way to mismatch a formatter with a type?

Comment: The function argument type is `any`, which `string` satisfies, therefor it compiles, the dynamic values are not evaluated until runtime. The compiler does not do extended static analysis, nor does it emit warnings, that is left for external tooling. The rationale is that is the design choice of the developers of the Go toolchain.

Comment: That is also just a format parsed by the `fmt` package, it’s not part of the language grammar, so the compiler really has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @JimB: thanks. Your second comment on `fmt` being just a package is indeed a good reason. Would you mind turning the comments into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fmt.Printf` format string argument is interpreted at runtime, not compile time.

> ```
> func Printf(format string, a ...any) (n int, err error)
> ```
>
> Printf formats according to a format specifier and writes to standard output. It returns the number of bytes written and any write error encountered.

Use a static analysis linter, for example, `go vet`.

> [go command - cmd/go - Go Packages](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go)
>
> Report likely mistakes in packages
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> go vet [-n] [-x] [-vettool prog] [build flags] [vet flags] [packages]
> ```
>
> Vet runs the Go vet command on the packages named by the import paths.
>
> For more about vet and its flags, see 'go doc cmd/vet'.

---

so.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := "hello"
    fmt.Printf("1 %w\n", s)
    fmt.Printf("2 %s\n", s)
}
```

linter:

```
$ go vet so.go
./so.go:7:2: fmt.Printf format %w has arg s of wrong type string, 
             see also https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#hdr-Printing
$
```

runtime:

```
$ go run so.go
1 %!w(string=hello)
2 hello
$
```